# Непонятные ошибки с datasource при деплое в jboss (wildfly) 14

Tags: java, wildfly

Делаю программу по этому [примеру](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaoSwULyB0w) . Вроде добавил в папку deployments jar с драйвером и файл с описанием datasource, но при деплоя на сервер (через отладку в IntelliJ IDEA) у меня пишется ошибка:

```
22:06:55,275 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "webapp-example-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exampleDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"webapp-example-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#examplePU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exampleDS]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"webapp-example-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#examplePU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exampleDS]"
    ]
}
```

Вот, мой файл с описанием datasource:

```
<?xml varsion="1.0"?>
    <datasources schemaLocation="http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd">
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="PostgreSQLPool">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</connection-url>
            <driver>postgresql-42.2.5.jar</driver>
      <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
            <pool>
                <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                <password>1</password>
            </security>
      <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
      </validation>
  </datasources>
```

Состав проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="examplePU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/exampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Почему возникает эти ошибки, и как их убрать?